# .val() of jquery not working for select element on IE

Tags: jquery

I tried all these for selected value of select element

```
inventory_rule = $("#inventory_rule :selected").attr('value');
inventory_rule = $("#inventory_rule option:selected").val();
inventory_rule = $("#inventory_rule").attr('value');
inventory_rule = $("#inventory_rule").val();
```

these all worked well in mozilla but not in IE

is any alternative

Comment: ¿Could you post the HTML of the <select>? ¿What version of jQuery and IE? I just checked, and $("#inventory_rule).val() works without problems in IE, "inventory_rule" being the ID of the <select> tag.

Answer (score 2):

The 4th of your attempts is the most straightforward way to get the selected value of a select element and it should work.

```
var inventory_rule = $("#inventory_rule").val();
```

I wrote a quick and [dirty example for you](http://jsfiddle.net/agwbu/) at jsfiddle.net, showing that it works.  This means that your selector is probably wrong.  Check and make sure the select element has `id="inventory_rule"` and **make sure that id attribute is also unique on the page**.  Don't forget the `var` keyword if it's the first time you're declaring the variable.

EDIT: highlighted the part about making sure the id attribute is unique, a non-unique id will definitely cause problems in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this earlier.

when getting the value of a

```
<select>
```

tag IE 10 inserts spaces before and after the value.
so just trim the value and it will solve your worries.

```
var inventory_rule = $.trim($("#inventory_rule").val());
```

Comment: I would have never figured that out. Geeze.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Comment: Only useful if he's submitting the form via ajax.

Comment: @Andy, I disagree - he could still make use of the `.value()` function within the plugin, without having to use the ajax functionality.

Comment: but then it's no different to using `.val()` to get the value of the element, which is what the plugin uses in its underlying code.