# Get value of select box IE with jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
var kontrakt = $("#kontrakt_select").find("option:selected").val();
```

returns undefined in IE(9) but works in Chrome and FireFox

```
<select id="kontrakt_select">
<option value="12345.1">19999.1 - 1992 ABC</option>
</select>
```

Can you explain how to get the selected value in IE iwth jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: jQuery lets you just do `$("#kontrakt_select").val()`; see the `val()` documentation http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: I have confirmed your code works in IE9. See http://jsfiddle.net/2m63X/. Where do you notice it is undefined?

Comment: agree with @AnthonyGrist. we need to know the context for this code.  as @Matt stated, you could do `$("#kontrakt_select").val()` to get the current value.  you can do this during the .change() for the select element, or you could use it somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I have tried $("#kontrakt_select").val() also. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is a link, that shows you, that your posted code runs in IE 7-9 ( jsfiddle.net/FsfDD/ ).

Maybe you have the same problem like in this post ( [.val() of jquery not working for select element on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245279/val-of-jquery-not-working-for-select-element-on-ie) ). There is the problem, that when an ID-Attribute in HTML is set to two or more elements, that means, the ID isn't unique, the selector doesn't work in older IE-Version. ( e.g. jsfiddle.net/tvmY7/ ).